# Templated operator overload does not compile if OpenCV headers are included

Tags: c++, opencv, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the left shift operator `<<` for a custom class, using a template and `std::enable_if` to use a single overload declaration & definition for both console / print output and file writing:

`Foo.hpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <type_traits>
// #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

namespace cv {
class Foo {
 public:
    
    Foo() { }


    ~Foo() { }
    const int mb = 78;

    static bool toFile(const Foo& instance);
};
}

template < typename OSTR_T,
                    typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of< std::ostream, OSTR_T >::value > >
OSTR_T& operator<<(OSTR_T& os, const cv::Foo& foo);
```

and `Foo.cpp`:

```
#include "Foo.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace cv {

bool Foo::toFile(const Foo& instance) {
    std::ofstream file("debug.txt", std::ios::app);
    file << instance;
    file.close();
    return true;
}
}  // namespace cv

template < typename OSTR_T, typename >
OSTR_T& operator<<(OSTR_T& os, const cv::Foo& foo) {
    os << foo.mb << "\n";
    return os;
}

template std::ofstream& operator<< < std::ofstream > (std::ofstream&, const cv::Foo&);
template std::ostream&  operator<< < std::ostream >  (std::ostream&, const cv::Foo&);
```

This approach compiles and works fine, however I need to use several tools provided by OpenCV to extend `Foo`, namely declaring some `cv::Point` and `cv::Mat` members.

Strangely, I've found that **simply including OpenCV's header** `opencv2/opencv.hpp` on `Foo.hpp` is enough for the code not to compile anymore, with the compiler for some reason becoming enable to find the `<<` overload:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ofstream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ofstream<char>’} and ‘const cv::Foo’)
9 |         file << instance;
  |         ~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~
  |         |       |
  |         |       const cv::Foo
  |         std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}
```

I've also noticed that this only happens **if I declare Foo within the cv:: namespace**. What exactly is happening here, how can including a header create such conflict?

Comment: Aside from what you're asking about, I'm curious what you expect to accomplish by using SFINAE this way, instead of simply declaring a template that takes a `std::ostream &` as the parameter?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I had actually not realized that `std::ofstream` was derived from `std::ostream`, and attempted to use a templated overload to fit both. I first started by declaring the overload as you suggest, but was getting the same compilation error.

Comment: If you did not realize "that `std::ofstream` was derived from `std::ostream`", then what exactly led you to implement SFINAE that uses `std::is_base_of< std::ostream ... >`, which tests for exactly that? Insofar as the reason for the original error, it's likely because the `cv` namespace defines its own `<<` overload, so once name lookup finds it, it won't attempt to do overload resolution in the global namespace. Moving your `<<` overload directly into the `cv` namespace will likely address this.